# how to post follow/unfollow with instagram api - php

Tags: php, api, curl, instagram

i want to post follow / unfollow with instagram api

i just dont understand where use to  ACTION 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uvyz.jpg)

i use this function to curl and see result:

```
function Execute_insta($url,$parametr=null)
{
    $cu = curl_init($url);
    if($parametr) {

        curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_POST,true);
        curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parametr);
    }
    curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($cu,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    $insta = curl_exec($cu);
    $insta = json_decode($insta,true);
    return $insta;

}
```

[instagram api url](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_followed_by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'action=follow');` should do the trick.

Comment: THANSK'S its working :))))
someone voteup please, i cant